# While statment loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I am learning python, and I am stuck in an infinite while loop in the following code.

```
A = input("Hello what is your name? ")
D = input("What is today's date? ")
B = input("Did you have a good day [y/N]")
while B != "y" or B != "Y" or B != "N" or B != "n":
    B = input("Did you have a good day [y/N]")
else:
    if B == "Y" or B == "y":
        print(A + ", ")
        C = input("Tell me about your day ")
        with open("Start.txt", "a") as infile:
            infile.write("\n")
            infile.write(A)
            infile.write(" ran Start.py and said he had a good day on ")
            infile.write(D)
            infile.write(".")
            infile.write("\n    He reports today:\n        ")
            infile.write(C)
    elif B == "N" or "n":
        print(A + ", ")
        C = input("Tell me about your day ")
        with open("Start.txt", "a") as infile:
            infile.write("\n")
            infile.write(A)
            infile.write(" ran Start.py and said he had a bad day on ")
            infile.write(D)
            infile.write(".")
            infile.write("\n    He reports today:\n        ")
            infile.write(C)
```

The problem happens when B is compared to see if it is equal to Y, y, N, or n
but it still no matter what input I give it for B sticks me into the while statement and keeps me there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
while B != "y" or B != "Y" or B != "N" or B != "n":
```

`B` is *always* not equal to one of those. If it's "y" it is not equal to the other three, and so on. And since you are using `or` to combine these conditions, the loop continues if any one is true, which, as we've seen, is always the case.

Rewrite using `and`:

```
while B != "y" and B != "Y" and B != "N" and B != "n":
```

Or apply DeMorgan's law (factor the `not` out of the expression and swap `and`/`or`):

```
while not (B == "y" or B == "Y" or B == "N" or B == "n"):
```

Or best of all, write it the Python way:

```
while B.lower() not in "yn":
```

(This also accepts an empty answer, which according to your prompt is equivalent to "N". To handle this, just convert your `elif` to a plain `else`, without a condition.)

Answer (score 1):

Lets use a simplified version of your while loop.

```
while B != "Y" or B != "y":
    # ...
```

There is no way that this will ever evaluate to `False`.

If B was set to `Y` then `B != "Y"` would be `False`, but `B != "y"` would be `True`.

I think, in this case, it might be cleaner to do something like

```
while B not in ["y", "Y", "n", "N"]:
    # ...
```

Which will then repeat until the input is one of the characters in your list.

*EDIT: Some other answers have suggested using `while B not in "yYnN"` or equivalents. This works here because all of your expected responses are one character. If you decide later to accept `"yes"` as a response, then you will have to use a list like I have shown above.*

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are doing `while B != "y" or B != "Y" or B != "N" or B != "n":`

With `or` it returns true if either of its options are true. So if B="N"
`b!="N" or b!=n"` is true because b still isn't "n"

You can solve this by replacing all the `or`s with `and`s to get this
`while B != "y" and B != "Y" and B != "N" and B != "n":`

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
elif B == "N" or "n":
```

Should be

```
elif B == "N" or B == "n":
```

You should use condition, simply `"n"` (non empty string) means `true`

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution!

```
while B not in "YNyn":
```